# Insert Stored Procedure mapped with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying based on some examples and Hibernate documentation for mapping a Stored Procedure, I just need to insert some data wich is not for a single table, but I got the message:

> *Could not parse mapping document from resource*

The mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Data">
        <id column="col_id" name="dataId">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property column="col_liq" name="dataLiq" />
        <property column="col_td" name="dataTd" />
        <property column="col_numdcto" name="dataNumDoc" />
        <sql-insert callable="true" check="none">
            {call sp_update_data(?,?,?,?)}
        </sql-insert>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The "Data" object is just a POJO.

I will appreciate any idea or sugestion.

Comment: Hello again, after a long time returning to this, I'm getting the next error:
PLS-00201: identifier 'sp_update_data' must be declared

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to let others to know how it works due finally I did it.
The mapping is correct with just one point, Hibernate will set the Id as the last field, so the procedure should get it in that position, at least that you do some "trick".
In Java when calling the procedure is like a normal *save*, the rest is like working with a normal entity.